# Как сохранять значение select и показывать на другой странице?

Tags: javascript, html, select

Этот код значение select'a пишет в span. Как бы сохранять выбранное значение (например, после клика на кнопку) куда-нибудь и использовать на другой странице?

**HTML:**

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>

<p>Value: <span id="value">0</span></p>
<p>Text: <span id="text">Select option</span></p>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectId").change(function() {
        $("#value").text($(this).val());
        $("#text").text($("#selectId option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

Comment: cookie, localStorage

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: не задавай один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. если нужно дополнить - правь старый

Comment: Там нету того что мне надо

Comment: Вам в предыдущем вопросе показли как хранить данные. Судя по вашим комментариям вы не поняли как их передавать внужные дивы.
Тогда так и сформулируйте свой вопрос, а не повторяйте старый

Comment: Я спросил в комментарии. Мне не ответили